# Concurrent access to a queue by multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm creating an application with a `NetTcpBinding` service and a `BasicHttpBinding` one.
Through these services, the clients send requests to the application: these requests must be put into a `Queue` object, that is the queue of inbound request.

1. Both services must allow concurrent calls from the clients.
2. This means that both services should access concurrently to the queue in order to add the received requests.
3. In addition, another thread must access the queue in order to get and process the requests.

I could use `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and so many calls could be taken simultaneously. However, this does not guarantee a concurrent access to the queue. Should I put the two `ServiceHost` in two different thread? For example:

- The first thread dequeues and processes the requests in the queue.
- The second thread instantiates the `NetTcpBinding` service and enqueues new requests in the queue. Moreover, it sends any replies via callback.
- The third thread instantiates the `BasicHttpBinding` service and enqueues new requests in the queue.

This is my idea.
Since I am almost a newbie, I would be grateful if you could give me some advice.
Maybe I should start writing three threads that access the queue concurrently: for the moment the first two threads may enqueue random requests to the queue, while the third thread consume these requests.

Comment: Are you bound to Queue?  Can you use a ConcurrentQueue or a BlockingCollection?  This is a pretty standard producer/consumer problem.

Comment: @Joe: For now I should use collections not thread-safe, like `Queue`, `Dictionary`, ect..

Comment: Any particular reason why?  You're just reimplementing the wheel most likely.

Comment: @Joe: Only educational reasons to learn how to manage the threads in C#. Later I will have to modify this application using thread-safe collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you characterize yourself as "I am almost a newbie" I would suggest you more general reading - [Threading in C# Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) free online article/book. It thoroughly reviews problems and instrumentation of threading in C#.

I assure you, careful reading of parts 3 and 4 (and reviewing part 1 and 2) will give you the tools to solve not only your current problem but a bunch of many other problems that you will meet on the way of multithreading.

If you just want a quick answer to your question, just follow Yahia's answer.

Answer (score 9):

IF you are on .NET 4 you should look into `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and `BlockingCollection`.

Bascially these are thread-safe collections which are implemented for high performance and are mostly lock-free.

`BlockingCollection` is specifically implemented for Producer-Consumer-Scenarios like the one you describe.

For reference see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/10/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrent-collections-1-of-3.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx